# Why we can't get Complexity/Function date by visit sonarqube API( /api/measures/component )

Tags: json, sonarqube, complexity-theory

sonarqube version: 7.9.1

I need get the date of Complexity / Function , but there is no page to show it in sonarqube. So I want to call sonar-API to get this value.

I have tested /api/measures/component and /api/measures/component_tree. But no value of Complexity/ Function.

I visit this link:

```
$sonarqube_site/api/measures/component_tree?metricKey=function_complexity&component=$project_key$additionalFields=metrics
```

I want to get the value of Complexity/Funtion

Comment: I test sonar5.6 version api, and find can get the value of Complexity/Function. If the reason is that sonar7.9 deprecate  Complexity/Function?

Comment: Can anyone tell me other ways to get the value of Complexity/Function? Thanks very much

Comment: See [here](http://javadocs.sonarsource.org/7.0/apidocs/org/sonar/api/measures/CoreMetrics.html); it looks like it is deprecated since 6.7. See also workitem [SONAR-8331](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-8331).

Comment: Thanks for your help. See it.   I see CoreMetrics  class have FUNCTION_COMPLEXITY properties. How can i get the value if this properties?  And if we can't get this value by api, could we get it by another way?